# Adjust anchor postion to make it appear close to the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css, anchor

Using the anchor in the URL

```
http://www.site.com/xxx.php#aaaa
```

will jump to where the anchor is

```
<a name="aaaa"></a>
```

But, it's right on the top the screen.

Is there anyway to offset this slight down so to fit in the middle? If it's a static page, I guess I can insert the anchor a bit higher. But I have a dynamic generated list.

Comment: Do you mind using javascript to scroll the page below by as many pixels as you want?

Comment: See my answer below. I can't guarantee that it'll be easy but I have tried to annotate as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following call to easily scroll your page by as much as you want:

```
window.scrollBy(0, 100)
```

The downside is that if you try doing this in your document.ready() event, it won't work since the browser can scroll to the desired element only after the whole page is loaded (including any javascript.) So, what to do?

Here is some annotated code to help you understand what is going on:

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(hash.length > 0 && $('#'+ hash).size() > 0){

        // Binds a function to the page scroll to be executed
        // only once at the first scroll.
        $(document).one('scroll', function(){

            // when the browser finishes loading the page, it will
            // scroll right to our element.
            var elemTop = $('#'+ hash).offset().top; // Retrieve element's offset top
            var docTop = $(document).scrollTop(); // Retrieve page's offset

            // if our element is right at the top of the page, we
            // want to scroll down a bit.
            if(elemTop == docTop) {
                //Adjust the amount of scrolling to the middle of the screen
                window.scrollBy(0, window.outerHeight/2);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I find out how many pixels that I need to move? I guess I need to know that right? See, the anchor frees me from knowing that...

Comment: @Jusfeel - You scroll by half the window's outerHeight. That'll always place your anchor in the middle since at the beginning of the scroll, your anchor was at the top. My comment in the code for adjusting the amount of scrolling exists only because scrolling to the middle of page may not look good. You may want to scroll by only 100px.

Comment: The downside you pointed out seems not a problem for me, yet. It's working. At least on Firefox.

Comment: @Jusfeel - Since it's working, any reasons not to accept/upvote it? Are you looking for something else?